# How to place two charts next to each other in plotly python?

Tags: python, html, plotly

I am not using subplots for this since the requirement is of legend beside the chart which is not possible by using subplots. Subplots only lets the legend at once place, hence I have thought of using to different plots and placing them beside each other.
Here is the code which produced two charts, but i am unable to place them beside each other.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['time'],y=data['x'],mode='lines',name='xyz',hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor=['white']),hovertemplate='abcd<br>Probability: %{y}'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['time'],y=predict_data['y'],mode='lines',name='abc'))
fig.update_layout(title='TRend charts',yaxis_title='Probabilities',autosize=False,width=1000,height=600,margin=dict(l=50,r=50,b=100,t=100,pad=4),paper_bgcolor='lightpink',xaxis_showgrid=False)
p_8 = opy.plot(fig,auto_open=False,output_type='div')

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['time'],y=data['xy'],mode='lines',name='xyz1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['time'],y=data['ab'],mode='lines',name='abc`'))
fig.update_layout(title='Second Chart',yaxis_title='Probabilities',autosize=False,width=100,height=600,margin=dict(l=50,r=-50,b=100,t=100,pad=3),paper_bgcolor='yellow',xaxis_showgrid=False)
p_9 = opy.plot(fig,auto_open=False,output_type='div')
```

I get them one below the other. Any attributes which can get them beside each other?

Comment: The *requirement*? Is this an assignment for a class or something?

Comment: No, my project requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fig = fig.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)
```

Comment: Hi, yes this works but the legend does not come beside each chart and that is why i am making seperate two charts...

Comment: Ok I think there is no such  think that you want to do because  what I know to use subplot  for such case